# How to migrate SafeNet MobilePASS seed to another TOTP app?

Tags: one-time-password, hotp

Based on [How does SafeNet MobilePASS generate passwords?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9157/1125), I'm not sure if the MobilePASS token can be extracted for use in another TOTP app such as andOTP or KeePassXC. (I guess it depends whether the MobilePASS algorithm is a standard one.) Is this possible? If so, how? Can I use the activation URL (so I don't even have to install MobilePASS), or do I need to extract it from the MobilePASS configuration?

The self-enrolment URL has these parameters:

- `code` is a 25 character ASCII alnum string.
- `data` is a pipe-separated string with a bunch of properties:

  1. Two zero-padded digits
  2. Two zero-padded digits
  3. My email address
  4. A 16-bit hex-encoded number
  5. A 16-bit hex-encoded number
  6. The string `0`
  7. The string `0`
  8. An 18-digit number
  9. The string `Unknown`
  10. A base-64 encoded string which decodes as `Mailflow|{"V":"0.0.0000","P":"Win32","AN":"Mail","WT":2}`
  11. The string `3000`
  12. Empty string
  13. Empty string
  14. Empty string
- `sdata` is a base-64 encoded string which decodes as 32 bytes of binary gibberish - no idea what the format is here, but it seems like a good candidate for the secret
- `reserved=0`

After going to the enrolment URL I get a base64-encoded string with the following decoded value:

```
EnrollmentURL=https://[redacted]?sc=[redacted 8-character ASCII alnum string]
UserID=[my username]
```

Is the `sc` value the relevant secret, encoded in some way? If I try to use the code directly as a TOTP secret the application (two separate ones) uppercase the string, and generate different codes from MobilePASS.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I believe the algo has changed again as the QR code contains the following payload... I cannot seem to get a response out of the URL but the MobilePass+ app does accept it so I think we just need to figure out the actual request that is sent from the app. EnrollmentURL=https://se.safenet-inc.com/selfenrollment/dskpp.aspx?sc=[sc]
UserID=[UserID]
Passphrase=[Passphrase]

Comment: Not really. I gave up after not getting any answers, and instead run this app on its own phone.